# Eclipse Plug-In developement. How to set exclusion filter programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sdk

I created a source folder with following code:

```
Folder folder = proj.getFolder("resources");
folder.create(false, true, null);
IPackageFragmentRoot root = jproject.getPackageFragmentRoot(folder);
IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = jproject.getRawClasspath();
IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(root.getPath());
jproject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);
i18Resource = folder;
```

Now I'd like to add `**` to its exclusion path like in this dialog:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variant of `JavaCore.newSourceEntry` that supports this:

```java
public static IClasspathEntry newSourceEntry(IPath path, IPath[] inclusionPatterns,
       IPath[] exclusionPatterns, IPath specificOutputLocation, 
       IClasspathAttribute[] extraAttributes)
```